# Any way to change order of photos in stack view?

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, stackview

Does anyone know how to change the order of photos in **stack view(both horizontal and vertical)** by **user's desire**?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34122961/1949494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddly way is to use

```
addArrangedSubview()
insertArrangedSubview()
removeArrangedSubview()
```

If you have more time, I'd consider looking into UICollectionView which has a lot more flexibility that StackViews, especially for things like rearrangement.

Comment: I mean not delete existing and adding new. For example like sorting table view, and i want to sort stack view.

Comment: That's the only way to do it with a UIStackView, the array of views it contains is read-only. Have a look at UICollectionView.

Comment: I sure would do. Thanks for your time and have a good day ^^